# several plots (scatter plot of a specific variable vs other variables) in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I modify this code to have all plots together and on one page(loop function)? In my real data set, I want to have the scatter plot between the dependent variable and 10 independent variables. The scatter plot between the dependent variable and each IV separately.

```
plot(rock$area, rock$peri)
plot(rock$area, rock$shape)
plot(rock$area, rock$perm)
```

Comment: Before the three plots,  type `par(mfrow=c(1,3))`

Comment: Probably best not to use the function name `plot` for a variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged your question with `ggplot2`, I'll assume that you are interested in a `ggplot2` solution.

```
rock <- data.frame(area  = sample(1:100, 10, replace = TRUE),
                   peri  = sample(1:100, 10, replace = TRUE),
                   shape = sample(1:100, 10, replace = TRUE), 
                   perm  = sample(1:100, 10, replace = TRUE))
```

Now we can make the data tidy (a column for y variable names, another column for y variable values) and use facets to create separate plots per y variable.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
rock %>% 
  gather(yvar, val, -area) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(area, val)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    facet_grid(yvar ~ .)
```

[image]